# Can't add table element to canvas Vuejs 3

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

I am trying to add table element inside canvas with vuejs, but it's not working.
The context is working because I can draw rectangle and another graphics elements.

I tried to implement 2 functions desenhar and desenhar2. But no success.

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { Head, Link } from '@inertiajs/vue3';

defineProps<{
    canLogin?: boolean;
    canRegister?: boolean;
}>();
</script>
<script lang="ts">
 
const desenhar2 = ()=>{
    let  canvas: HTMLCanvasElement = <HTMLCanvasElement> document.getElementById("canvas");
   console.log(canvas);
    let ctx :CanvasRenderingContext2D  = <CanvasRenderingContext2D> canvas.getContext("2d");
    var data = "<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='200' height='200'>" +
        "<foreignObject width='100%' height='100%'>"+
            '<table id="tabela_modelo"><tr><td>html table to</td><td>canvas test</td></tr></table>'+
        "</foreignObject>" +
        "</svg>";
    var DOMURL = self.URL || self.webkitURL || self;
    var img = new Image();
    var svg = new Blob([data.toString()], {
        type: "image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8"
    });
    var url = DOMURL.createObjectURL(svg);
    img.onload = function() {
        ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
        DOMURL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    };
    img.src = url;
}


</script>
<template>
    <Head title="Modelador De Banco de Dados" />

    <div id="container" class=" dark:bg-gray-900">
        <div class="cabecalho bg-lime-300">
            <h1>Modelador de Banco De Dados</h1>
            <nav class="nav">
                <button @click="desenhar2" class="nav-item btn p-1 bg-lime-200 border-emerald-500 border-2 mx-1 rounded text-bold">
                    <font-awesome-icon icon="arrow-pointer" />
                    <br />
                    <small>Selecionar</small>
                </button>               
            </nav>

        </div>
        <div id="conteudo" class="conteudo bg-gray-100">
            <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style='font-size:12px'>  
            <table id="tabela_modelo">
            <tr>
                <td>html table to</td>
                <td>canvas test</td>
            </tr>        
        </table>
        </div>
            <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<style type="text/css">

#canvas {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: aqua;
    border: 1px solid red;
    color:black;
}</style>
```

Just want render a table inside canvas with VueJs 3